# how to delete table entry in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please help me. I am new to javascript. I want my table entries deleted on form itself when user selects row using javascript and html.
I tried delet function but it remove heading too which i dont want. user should select row and it should be deleted.

html code:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <h2>Receipt</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="ctype">Charge Type</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input id="ctype" name="ctype" placeholder="--" style="border: none;" type="text" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="amt">Amount</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input id="amt" name="amt" placeholder="--" style="border: none;" type="text" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="camt">Cash Amount</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label>100</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br><input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" style="border: none; height:30px; width:100px;" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="button" style="border: none; height:30px; width:100px;" onClick="updateForm();"/>Add To Table</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="button" style="border: none; height:30px; width:100px;" onClick="saveForm()" />Save</button>
        <button type="button" style="border: none; height:30px; width:100px;" onClick="deletRow()" />Remove</button>
    </form>
    <br>

     <table id="results" width="360">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" width="120">Charge Type</th>
            <th scope="col" width="120">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <table id="resultTotals" width="360">
    <tr>
        <td scope="col" width="120">Totals</td>
        <td scope="col" width="120"><div id="amtTotals"></div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
  var amtTotal = 0;

        function updateForm() {
            var ctype = document.getElementById("ctype").value;
            var amt = document.getElementById("amt").value;
            amtTotal = amtTotal + parseInt(amt);
            document.getElementById("amtTotals").innerHTML=amtTotal;

            var table=document.getElementById("results");
            var row=table.insertRow(-1);
            var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML=ctype;
            cell2.innerHTML=amt;   

        }

        function saveForm() {
             if( amtTotal < 100 ){
                alert("Thank you");
             } else
             {
                alert("Invalid Amount")
             } 
        }

        function deletRow() {
    document.getElementById("results").deleteRow(0);
}

 </script>
```

Thank You. Sorry for grammar.

Comment: row 0 is heading so it's deleted . you need to delete single row after header or all row after header ?

Comment: i want to delete selected row but I dont know how to apply it in javascript

Comment: is it okay to use jquery ?

Comment: If its Possible then no problem.

Comment: try my below answer @pkm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) create checkbox for each row

2) based on checkbox remove the row

3) while remove you need to minus the current row amount in total amount like this

4) And there was a trick you need to delete the row from last like bottom to top . if you delete the row top to bottom it will throw row index error.

```js
var amtTotal = 0;

        function updateForm() {
            var ctype = document.getElementById("ctype").value;
            var amt = document.getElementById("amt").value;
            amtTotal = amtTotal + parseInt(amt);
            document.getElementById("amtTotals").innerHTML=amtTotal;

            var table=document.getElementById("results");
            var row=table.insertRow(-1);
            var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
   var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
            cell1.innerHTML=ctype;
            cell2.innerHTML=amt;   
   cell3.innerHTML='<input type="checkbox" name="deletee" value="1" >';   

        }

        function saveForm() {
             if( amtTotal < 100 ){
                alert("Thank you");
             } else
             {
                alert("Invalid Amount")
             } 
        }

        function deletRow() {
    //document.getElementById("results").deleteRow(0);
 
 var table = document.getElementById('results');
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  
  //alert(rowCount);
  
           var row_ids =[];
        // var i=1 to start after header
        for(var i=rowCount-1; i>=rowCount-(rowCount-1); i--) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            // index of td contain checkbox is 8
   if(row)
   {
    var chkbox = row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    var current_row_amount = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
    //alert(chkbox.checked);
    if('checkbox' == chkbox.type && true == chkbox.checked) {
     
     //row_ids.push(i);
          table.deleteRow(i);
       amtTotal= amtTotal-parseInt(current_row_amount);
       document.getElementById("amtTotals").innerHTML=amtTotal;
     
     }
   }
        }

   }
```

```html
<form>
        <h2>Receipt</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="ctype">Charge Type</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input id="ctype" name="ctype" placeholder="--" style="border: none;" type="text" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="amt">Amount</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input id="amt" name="amt" placeholder="--" style="border: none;" type="text" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="camt">Cash Amount</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label>100</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br><input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" style="border: none; height:30px; width:100px;" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="button" style="border: none; height:30px; width:100px;" onClick="updateForm();"/>Add To Table</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="button" style="border: none; height:30px; width:100px;" onClick="saveForm()" />Save</button>
        <button type="button" style="border: none; height:30px; width:100px;" onClick="deletRow()" />Remove</button>
    </form>
    <br>

     <table id="results" width="360">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" width="120">Charge Type</th>
            <th scope="col" width="120">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
    </table>

    <table id="resultTotals" width="360">
    <tr>
        <td scope="col" width="120">Totals</td>
        <td scope="col" width="120"><div id="amtTotals"></div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: glad to help you @pkm